# Use ref with and height

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, use-ref

I was wondering how to get useRef width and height on load and when it changes.

I am trying to pass the exact dimensions of a component to its child.

**MapContainer.js**

```
const mapComponent = useRef(null);
const [mapWidth, setMapWidth] = useState(0);
const [mapHeight, setMapHeight] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (mapComponent.current !== null) {
      setMapWidth(mapComponent.current.clientWidth);
      setMapHeight(mapComponent.current.clientHeight);
    }
  }, [mapComponent]);

<div className={`bg-white rounded-[32px] overflow-hidden relative`} ref={mapComponent}>
   <Map
     style="mapbox://styles/ayagoumi/ckyvm0dx5001714mplg2y1oz7"
     zoom={zoom}
     center={position}
     movingMethod="easeTo"
     containerStyle={{
       height: `${mapHeight}px`, // this is what i want to change
       width: `${mapWidth}px`, // this is what i want to change
       borderRadius: "32px",
       zIndex: "0",
       overflow: "hidden",
     }}
   >
   </Map>
</div>
```

**Index.js**

```
<section className="flex flex-wrap justify-between w-full gap-4 xl:flex-nowrap">
     <div></div>
     <div className="flex flex-col order-2 gap-4 sm:flex-row grow">
       <MapContainer styles="w-full md:!w-[50%] lg:w-full min-w-[300px] min-h-[300px] order-2 rounded-[32px] overflow-hidden"></MapContainer>
     </div>
</section>
```

But this approach that I took is not getting me the width and height when parent width changes

Comment: How and where are you using `mapComponent` ? Without seeing how it works, it's impossible to know.

Comment: I am using it in index.js at Home component

Comment: Please show the code on where and how you use it. Add that code to your question.

Comment: @Vencovsky Check the edit

Comment: I don't see where you use the `mapComponent` ref. Sorry but your question have a lot of missing info. Also, you have a typo in `if (mapCont.current !== null) {`, probably it should be `if (mapComponent.current !== null) {`

Comment: @Vencovsky I have made an edit, **mapComponent** ref width and height should be given to **Map** Component in order for it to take the same dimensions as it parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the new width and height after resizing, you need to listen to resize event of window, as example:

```
const Map = () => {
  const mapComponent = useRef(null);
  const [mapWidth, setMapWidth] = useState(0);
  const [mapHeight, setMapHeight] = useState(0);
  
  const onResize = () => {
    const rect = mapComponent.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect) {
      setMapWidth(rect.width);
      setMapHeight(rect.height);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={mapComponent}>
      <Child width={mapWidth} height={mapHeight}>A</Child>
      <Child width={mapWidth} height={mapHeight}>B</Child>
      <Child width={mapWidth} height={mapHeight}>C</Child>
      <Child width={mapWidth} height={mapHeight}>D</Child>
    </div>
  );
};
```